# Theory - How to Tell if Elements Overlap?

Tags: c++, vector, collision-detection, theory

I have a question, and I don't want an implementation. I just want a bit of help in my reasoning.

I want to determine if two objects overlap (their x and y coordinates, as well as their height and width are stored in a vector) and then, if they do, remove them from their current vector and add them to another with combined properties.

My question is, generally, how do you tell when something overlaps? Obviously, they can have the same x and not overlap due to differing y's, or vice versa. I am thinking I need information about the width and height in addition to the location of the edge of the object, but I don't even know how to turn this into pseudo code at present.

Any help in helping me figure this out would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** The objects are strictly rectangular, and the coordinates follow a pixel monitor convention. i.e. 0,0 is the upper left corner of the object, and an increase in x corresponds to going right, while an increase in y means going downwards.

Comment: These are strictly rectangular objects?

Comment: Yes, they are strictly rectangular.

Comment: And (x,y) coordinate is in the center of the object?

Comment: Nope. See edit, my apologies.

Comment: And are they axis-aligned? That is, do their sides are always parallel to the X and Y axes?

Comment: Oh, the question mentions "x, y, width and height", which implicitly means axis-aligned. I guess we programmers don't think that rectangles are actually more general than that!

Answer (score 1):

Consider two rectangles R1 and R2.

Overlap in x:

```
if (R2.x < R1.x + R1.width) AND (R1.x < R2.x + R2.width)
```

Overlap in y

```
if (R2.y < R1.y + R1.height) AND (R1.y < R2.y + R2.height)
```

PS. Note that Im using a pseudolanguage

Comment: Only handles axis-aligned rectangles, which might be fine, but not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I guess he mentions in question. He said height and width, which imply axis-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

A particularly bad (but intuitive) way of doing this is along this line of reasoning:

If two 2D rectangles overlap, then definitely some of the sides of one of them intersects some of the sides of the other. Actually, even if one of the line segments making up one of them intersects one of the line segments of the other, then the rectangles overlap.

So, you can just loop over their sides and check their intersection pair by pair. Finding code or ideas for *line segment intersection* shouldn't be hard at all.

Important note: you need to define for yourself whether sharing a side between the rectangles constitutes overlapping or not. If it doesn't, then you have to be extra careful in the implementation of the above method.

For axis-aligned rectangles (rectangles with sides parallel to the axes,) the solution is quite simpler:

Assume the two rectangles are named `A` and `B`, and assume and their 4 sides are named `left` (minimum X coordinate) , `right` (maximum X coordinate), `top` (minimum Y coordinate) and `bottom` (maximum Y coordinate.) Then I think you can say that they overlap if (and only if) *any* of these is true:

1. `A.right` is less than `B.left` (A is completely to the left of B)
2. `A.left` is greater than `B.right` (A is completely to the right of B)
3. `A.bottom` is less than `B.top` (A is completely above B)
4. `A.top` is greater than `B.bottom` (A is completely below of B)

In (somewhat) pseudo code, you can write:

```
if (A.right < B.left || A.left > B.right || A.bottom < B.top || A.top > B.bottom)
    /* don't overlap */
```

or written in another (more symmetrical and maybe easier to understand) form:

```
if (A.right < B.left || B.right < A.left || A.bottom < B.top || B.bottom < A.top)
    /* don't overlap */
```

Again note that rectangles with touching sides need to be handled with a little care.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a picture will help. This is your coordinate system with two objects.

[image]

Two objects overlap on x axis if the distance between `x1` and `x2` is smaller than the width of the object that's closer to the x axis (`w1` in the case on the picture).

pseudocode:

```
w = width of leftmost object
if ( abs (x1-x2) < w ) /* overlap on x axis */
```

You need to do the same for y axis. If both checks return true, the objects overlap.